# writing python code to make calls from terminal?

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a program that runs the following command in my terminal in ubuntu:

"xselect @ nameofscript"

I am debugging someones code who used this code to perform the feat:

```
def runXSelect(scriptname):

    '''This function will automatically run any xselect script input.
    It returns the stdout. Since it does not natively overwrite 
    existing pha files, in FileHelper, the write script will handle 
    this'''

    cmd = "xselect @ " + scriptname
    args = shlex.split(cmd)
    out = ""
    with subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                          universal_newlines=True,shell=True) as proc:


        proc.wait()
        out = proc.stdout.read()

    return out
```

The error that I am getting from the stdout is:

```
@: 1: @: xselect: not found
```

If I simply type the command in on the terminal, it runs fine. But something about the code is causing the execution to fail.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try using `cmd` instead of `args`. I think with `shell=True` you don't need to split. Read through https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor

Comment: @AlexHall I tried your solution, and I got a similar error message:                                   /bin/sh: 1: xselect: not found

Comment: Use the full path to xselect. You can find it with `which xselect` in the terminal.

Comment: @AlexHall When I use the full path to xselect, I get an error saying                 **error while loading shared libraries: libxself_6.20.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory**